Why did Lelouch suddenly laugh at the end of episode 17 of season 1?
At the end of episode 17 of season 1, Lelouch suddenly laughs.
Why does knowing that Suzaku is his arch-nemesis make him laugh like that?

i thought it was due to shock and disbelief the laughter might have been as an  expression of shock and disbelief at the irony of the situation.
